# Raspbian log files

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

Where can I find all boot, driver or kernel related logs on a Raspbian?
Could you please reply with a list as follows:

- Driver logs - /something/somethingelse.log

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/var/log/messages` should contain all kernel- and driver-related information.

It may miss some things happening early in boot, before the logging daemon was started. `dmesg` command should print the same log and also include the events that happened early in boot process.